# JavaScript - Bitwise XOR on strings?

Tags: javascript, encryption, xor

I'm translating an encryption function from PHP to JS.

PHP: (Both $y and $z are ASCII characters, so $x is inherently an ASCII oddity.)

```
 $x = ($y ^ $z);
```

Doing the same in JS results in $x = 0.

I tried:

```
 $x = String.fromCharCode(($y).charCodeAt(0).toString(2) ^ ($z).charCodeAt(0).toString(2));
```

But it gets to a different result.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't need to convert it back to a string. Bitwise operators work on numbers. `1 ^ 3`<sub>10</sub> is the same as `1 ^ 11`<sub>2</sub> is the same as `1 ^ 10`<sub>3</sub>.

```
//this should work for single characters.
x = String.fromCharCode(y.charCodeAt(0) ^ z.charCodeAt(0));
```

Answer (score 10):

The `toString(2)` converts to a binary *String*, but you want to work on the Number type.

Simply drop the `toString(2)` part and it should work.